# Image expands the table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablecell

I have an **600x90 picture** and I want a table cell with **exactly 600x90 dimensions**.

But I tried **overflow:hidden** and some other solution on the net, **but it still expands the table cell for a couple of pictures.**

The best I could get so far is 600x93 but it leaves **3 empty pixels** at the bottom, which looks very awkward!

Can someone help me on finding a solution?

Comment: can you post your source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

images by default have

```
display:inline
```

which in most browsers adds 3-5 pixels to it's height.

Try setting the css for the picture like this:

```
table.myTable td.withImage img { display:block; }
```

and see if it works.

Comment: images by default have display: inline-block

Comment: @Tomas: That might be possible, but inline-block means, that element itself behaves like it's block (thus w/h works, padding works), but in flow it acts as if it was inline, therefore that's the part of it's behavior that counts in this case... so basically, it's inline :)

Comment: @Tomas, but: 'An image has display: inline by default' [http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html ] and both webkit inspector and firebug give 'inline', so I don't think taht inline-block it is.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen in some browsers where the default image display type is inline, and it sits above some imaginary line. Try adding display:block to your image class.

If this doesn't help, let us know if its a cross-browser problem or just FF/IE/whatever. Also an example could help.