# Img with max-height:100% stretches table with manually set height

Tags: css, image, html-table, percentage

This is [minimal code example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okdimok/Yfmvj/2/).

Practically, I want to make a table 2x2 of images, fix its height and height of its rows and make images chose their size using `max-width` and `max-height`. But for some reason the table is bigger, than the div it's contained in and img height:100% makes it 100% it's high, but not container's. Why is it so? Where can I read about it?

Comment: You might want to see this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791033/image-expands-the-table-cell

Comment: AFAIK, that question is about additional bottom-margin in inline elements for letters g,q etc. Anyway, I've already tried it with no success:(

Comment: @Vikas Excuse me, that was me badly formulating the question at night:) You were correct answering that question, but i had another question in mind:)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if you actually define the height in the height attribute of the table cell, like this:

```
<td height="20px">
```

Comment: That does o_0. And why css doesn't? Is there any difference in defenitions? Still it's not working, if I specify height='100%' for table, tbody, tr, td...

Comment: That I couldn't tell you... Its my experience that if something works in html, and it works across all browsers and isn't too hard to implement, you go with it, because you can bang your head against the wall forever trying to figure out why css doesn't behave the way it is documented to, and especially why browsers have seemingly completely different ways of rendering things, but thats just my own opinion...